# Regular addition or multiplication operators in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

How can I write a scheme program that makes regular sums. In scheme 2+2 is written (+ 2 2). The program I have to make should make (2 + 2) possible is scheme.

Comment: Your question is almost entirely lacking in detail.  Can you describe more precisely what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking for a very simple evaluator for arithmetic expressions. Assuming that the only operator supported is addition and that both operands are numbers (not other addition expressions), it's as straightforward as this:

```
(define (sum-eval exp)
  (match exp
    [(list op1 '+ op2) (+ op1 op2)]
    [_ exp]))

(sum-eval '(1 + 1))
=> 2
```

To make things a bit more interesting, we could allow for the evaluation of nested subexpressions, just by recursively evaluating the operands:

```
(define (sum-eval exp)
  (match exp
    [(list op1 '+ op2) (+ (sum-eval op1) (sum-eval op2))]
    [_ exp]))

(sum-eval '((2 + 3) + (8 + 2)))
=> 15
```

Now that we're at it, we could add more operations to our evaluator:

```
(define (mini-eval exp)
  (match exp
    [(list op1 '* op2) (* (mini-eval op1) (mini-eval op2))]
    [(list op1 '+ op2) (+ (mini-eval op1) (mini-eval op2))]
    [_ exp]))

(mini-eval '((3 * 3) + (5 * 2)))
=> 19
```

And so on, and so on - you get the idea. Exercise for the reader: graceful handling of error conditions.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted and more. I didn't think I sounded that unclear to someone who knows scheme. If only I would have had this a few hours before I would have gotten an A- in the course =/. How do you reward points I'm new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to convert Scheme's prefix notation into infix notation:

```
(define (prefix->infix form)
  (cond ((number? form) form)
        ((list?   form)
         (assert (= 3 (length form)))
         (let ((operator (list-ref form 0))
               (operand1 (prefix->infix (list-ref form 1)))
               (operand2 (prefix->infix (list-ref form 2))))
           (list operand1 operator operand2)))
        (else 'error)))
```

Seems to work:

```
> (prefix->infix '(+ 2 2))
(2 + 2)
> (prefix->infix '(+ (- 3 2) (* 5 6)))
((3 - 2) + (5 * 6))
```

Comment: Close enough but not really. Thanks though